# Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB1:wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock

Tags: 20.04, directory, ubuntu-mate

Since going to 20.04 I have been seeing some odd behaviors.

Thunar and Caja are not seeing Maxtor_SDB1.

```
lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1695
loop1    7:1    0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
loop2    7:2    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
loop3    7:3    0    62M  1 loop /snap/core20/1587
loop4    7:4    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
loop5    7:5    0 400.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/112
loop6    7:6    0    47M  1 loop /snap/snapd/16292
loop7    7:7    0    48M  1 loop /snap/snapd/17336
loop8    7:8    0   284K  1 loop /snap/snapd-desktop-integration/14
loop9    7:9    0    16K  1 loop /snap/software-boutique/57
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   513M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda3   8:3    0   1.8T  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0  98.4G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 199.7G  0 part /media/andy/MAXTOR_SDB2
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Here is what occurs using Caja.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When I rebooted it is working again. But this problem occurs periodically?

Comment: It could be the drive was disconnected.   Take an other usb cable. Make a check fro the Filesystem.

Comment: Should I open my case after turning off computer and unplug and re-plug drive cable? @nobody

Answer (score -1):

I used gpart to repair the disk(partition).

```
sudo gpart -f /dev/sdb1
```

Some info here on gpart.

```
https://www.kali.org/tools/gpart/
```